# Android P: Service behavior changes

Tags: java, android, service, background-service

I was recently fiddling around with the newest Android P version, trying to run a simple Service with the `START_STICKY` flag.
Basically, this is my setup:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.d(TAG, "onTaskRemoved()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        Log.d(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Of course, I've added a service entry into the application's AndroidManifest file.
Testing the application on my older phone running Android Nougat, everything works as expected. 
This is how the lifecycle looks like after starting the app:

**On Android N**

1. onCreate()
2. onStartCommand()

Now, after swiping off the application from the recents menu:

3. onTaskRemoved()
4. onCreate()
5. onStartCommand()

This is the behavior that I expect. But when I launch the application on my newer phone running Android P DP4 the lifecycle looks like this, when starting the app:

**On Android P**

1. onCreate()
2. onStartCommand()

So far, nothing different. But when I clear the app from the recent menu:

3. onTaskRemoved()
4. onCreate()
5. onDestroy()

Thanks to the `START_STICKY`flag, the service restarts, but instantly gets destroyed, even before having the chance to run the `onStartCommand` method.

Are there any changes that I am not aware of? The only changes to something service related that I could find are documented [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes). And it only describes that a foreground service now needs a specific permission to work. However, I am running a background service, and thus this information seems to be irrelevant to me.

Did anyone experience similar problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try making the service be a foreground service in `onCreate()`, and see if that helps. My guess is that you are seeing changes that were introduced in Android 8.0 regarding background services.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking in the behavioral changes of the wrong Android version. Android Oreo introduced [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) which limits services in the background. TL;DR: Starting a service in the background will throw an `IllegalStateException`, use `Jobs` instead.